# How to download larg file from aws s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

im trying to download the [functional map of the world dataset](https://github.com/fMoW/dataset). It is stored in aws s3. The [github page](https://github.com/fMoW/dataset) of the dataset only describes how to download a .json file from the bucket, but not the record itself. I tried to download the whole bucket with `aws s3 cp s3://spacenet-dataset/Hosted-Datasets/fmow/fmow-rgb/`, which returns the error that this path doesn't exist.

Does anyone know which commands I need to download the data? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should be running if you're copying a specific prefix is the following command

```
aws s3 cp s3://spacenet-dataset/Hosted-Datasets/fmow/fmow-rgb . --recursive
```

Or if you want the whole bucket then the following

```
aws s3 cp s3://spacenet-dataset . --recursive
```

In this case the `.` will copy to your current directory so if you want it to go to another directory specify the path by replacing the `.` argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [aws s3 sync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html):

```
aws s3 sync s3://spacenet-dataset/Hosted-Datasets/fmow/fmow-rgb/ .
```

where `.` is the current working folder.

Or

```
aws s3 sync s3://spacenet-dataset/Hosted-Datasets/fmow/fmow-rgb/ <path-to-dest-folder>
```

where `<path-to-dest-folder>` is an existing folder.